# Creating a new ABRecord

Tags: iphone

HI all,

I am developing an application which relates with ABAddressBook. The issue is I want to
 create a new record and add it to the AddressBook. But in api docs , I didnt find  any thing related to creating a new record .

Best Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ABPersonCreate function to create new person record or ABGroupCreate to create a group.
    You can also use standard ABNewPersonViewController which provides native UI to create and fill data for a person record.